# Create new independent dataframe from an existing one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a dataframe looks like this:

```
TripId                   time_LAT_LON                                                     
  0      [['2017-07-22 07:49:01',43.96529, -76.50005], ['2017-07-22 07:50:01',43.96046, -76.50513],....
```

how can I extract *LAT* and *LON* values from   *time_LAT_LON* column and save them into a new dataframe for further calculations?

I don't want to modify original dataframe so i think of creating a new dataframe :

```
new_df=df.copy(deep=true)
for i , sublst in enumerate(new_df['time_LAT_LON']):
            del(sublst[0])
```

But the *time* values in original dataframe is deleted too.

by the way , I don't want to iterate through original dataframe and actually want *LAT* and *LON* values in new independent dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Series.apply`

```py
out = df['time_LAT_LON'].apply(lambda lsts: [lst[1:] for lst in lsts]).to_frame('LAT_LON')
```

```
print(out)

                                          LAT_LON
0  [[43.96529, -76.50005], [43.96046, -76.50513]]
```

Or you can try explode if you want output to separated column

```py
out = pd.DataFrame(df['time_LAT_LON'].explode().tolist(), columns='time_LAT_LON'.split('_')).drop(columns='time')
# or
out = df['time_LAT_LON'].explode().apply(pd.Series).set_axis('time_LAT_LON'.split('_'), axis=1).drop(columns='time')
```

```
print(out)

        LAT       LON
0  43.96529 -76.50005
0  43.96046 -76.50513
```

Comment: thank you very much. since deep copy doesn't work anymore . How can we make a copy of an entire dataframe with multiple columns  into a new independent dataframe in general? Is there any straighforward command for that like deep copy?

Comment: @milad Nothing to do with deep copy dataframe but you use `del` to delete element from dataframe.